# Rxjs: Repeat an Ajax Call Every X Seconds, but Wait for the Last One to Complete

Tags: ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to query an API every x seconds when subscribing to an autorefresher Observable, making sure that the last request has completed before sending another one.

```
let autoRefresher = new Observable().exhaustMap(() => Observable.defer(() => {
    return someService.returningAPromise();
}).timeout(refreshIntervalInMs).repeat());
```

Is there a better way to do this? How could I update the refresh interval without creating a new observable each time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

function doRequest() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
    return Observable.of('HTTP Response').delay(3000);
  } else {
    return Observable.of('HTTP Response');
  }
}

let autoRefresher = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .exhaustMap(doRequest)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/7HAib10r6Vdl1x2U2wFS

This randomly makes 3s delay. Operator `timer()` periodically emits a value. Then [exhaustMap()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) subscribes to the preceding Observable and ignores all Observables emitted until the current one completes. So `timer()` is emitting values but these are ignored by `exhaust()`.

Btw, note that I'm using TypeScript.

Comment: Nice, simpler than I thought. Out of interest, what is the Math.random() for?

Comment: @sqwk That's only to simulate requests that overlap.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is quite an old issue, I just wanted to bring up maybe a more "stable" solution. The problem with this approach is there might be windows where no request is made since the timer rans at a fixed 1s interval.

For example:

Interval 1s, Request Duration < 1s: Every 1second a request is made, but if the request takes for example 400ms to complete, it will only take 600ms until the next request starts (not 1 second)
Interval 1s, Request Duration 1,5s: Request starts at the beginning, in next interval request is still running so exhaustMap filters it, and in 3rd interval request will run again (500ms after previous request)

In my example the request will **always wait 1 second before running again**

```
import { delay, flatMap, repeat, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of,Subject } from 'rxjs';

function doRequest() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
        return Observable.of('HTTP Response').delay(3000);
    } else {
        return Observable.of('HTTP Response');
    }
}


const subject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
of(null)
    .pipe(
        // can be used to cancel
        takeUntil(subject),
        // does request
        flatMap(doRequest),
        // delays by 1second
        delay(1000),
        // repeat steps above
        repeat(),
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(respons);
    });
```

Comment: However, this delays the first request as well as any subsequent items are stale by the time they are emitted to the subscriber. So if , for ex., you want the interval to be 60s the request will complete, be delayed 60s, and the data may be stale by that time.

Comment: the first request is acutally not delay, check docs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay or stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-twjn8r?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100 . I don't know what you mean subsequent items are stale?

Answer (score 1):

It is important that the takeUntil(..) is the last call in the pipe(). Otherwise the observables might not be cancelled. See https://cartant.medium.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef